# Variationnal auto-encoder: implementing warm-up in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I recently read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.02282.pdf) which introduces a process called "Warm-Up" (WU), which consists in multiplying the loss in the KL-divergence by a variable whose value depends on the number of epoch (it evolves linearly from 0 to 1)

I was wondering if this is the good way to do that:

```
beta = K.variable(value=0.0)

def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    # cross entropy
    xent_loss = K.mean(objectives.categorical_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean))

    # kl divergence
    for k in range(n_sample):
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0.,
                              std=1.0)  # used for every z_i sampling
        # Sample several layers of latent variables
        for mean, var in zip(means, variances):
            z_ = mean + K.exp(K.log(var) / 2) * epsilon

            # build z
            try:
                z = tf.concat([z, z_], -1)
            except NameError:
                z = z_
            except TypeError:
                z = z_

            # sum loss (using a MC approximation)
            try:
                loss += K.sum(log_normal2(z_, mean, K.log(var)), -1)
            except NameError:
                loss = K.sum(log_normal2(z_, mean, K.log(var)), -1)
        print("z", z)
        loss -= K.sum(log_stdnormal(z) , -1)
        z = None
    kl_loss = loss / n_sample
    print('kl loss:', kl_loss)

    # result
    result = beta*kl_loss + xent_loss
    return result

# define callback to change the value of beta at each epoch
def warmup(epoch):
    value = (epoch/10.0) * (epoch <= 10.0) + 1.0 * (epoch > 10.0)
    print("beta:", value)
    beta = K.variable(value=value)

from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
wu_cb = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, log: warmup(epoch))


# train model
vae.fit(
    padded_X_train[:last_train,:,:],
    padded_X_train[:last_train,:,:],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    verbose=0,
    callbacks=[tb, wu_cb],
    validation_data=(padded_X_test[:last_test,:,:], padded_X_test[:last_test,:,:])
)
```

Comment: Looks like that will work. Though I think the answer [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2595) might be a little cleaner: Send your callback the beta parameter, that way you don't have to keep it as a global like you're doing above.

Comment: thank you I hadn't seen that thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will not work. I tested it to figure out exactly why it was not working. The key thing to remember is that Keras creates a static graph once at the beginning of training.

Therefore, the `vae_loss` function is called only once to create the loss tensor, which means that the reference to the `beta` variable will remain the same every time the loss is calculated. However, your `warmup` function reassigns beta to a new `K.variable`. Thus, the `beta` that is used for calculating loss is a different `beta` than the one that gets updated, and the value will always be 0.

It is an easy fix. Just change this line in your `warmup` callback:

`beta = K.variable(value=value)`

to:

`K.set_value(beta, value)`

This way the actual value in `beta` gets updated "in place" rather than creating a new variable, and the loss will be properly re-calculated.

Comment: Don't forget to set `beta._trainable = False`! Otherwise, the learning alg. manipulates the variable and the learning becomes unstable. For now, only the "dirty" private variable manip. is available. ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31089

Comment: @Tik0 I don't think that's necessary. I tried adding warmup to the current Keras VAE example (https://gist.github.com/pnb/0b66a49e40f18b9c77f2ade7cc5b039c) and it seems like the value of `beta` does not change during training. It can't hurt to set `_trainable = False`, though!

Comment: @Nigel I'm using it as `tensorflow_probability.layers.KLDivergenceRegularizer(prior, weight=beta)`. It gets included in the "Trainable params" count unless I set `beta._trainable=False`. I didn't test but I guess that without `_trainable=False` that it updates every batch, and then gets reset to the deterministic value at the end of every epoch.