# Keras - epoch dependant loss function

Tags: deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm working with the Keras framework and I would like to implement an epoch dependent loss function (i.e the loss function isn't the same at each epoch)

How would you do that ? Can you add an example, for instance based on [the keras VAE tutorial ?](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by recompiling the network. The weights are saved not changed by the recompilation. So in essence something like this:

```
for epoch in range(nb_epoch):
     loss_function = loss_for_epoch(epoch)
     model.compile(optimizer, loss_function, metrics)
     model.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=1)
```

Comment: In that case your callback modifies the learning rate, while I would like to modify the loss function itself.
It has the form: l(x, x_decoded) = a(x, x_decoded) + beta(t) * b(x, x_decoded) and beta(t) should be updated at each epoch

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Indeed it should work. I suppose it can take some time to recompile at each epoch ? But that is a solution, thank you

Comment: The weights of the model aren't affected in any way by the recompiling ?

Comment: Recompiling builds the loss fuction. I do not think that it is possible without and yes the weights should not change.

Comment: it seems it would be cleaner in this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787181/variationnal-auto-encoder-implementing-warm-up-in-keras/43102987#43102987

Comment: But wouldn't recompiling clear the past first order and second order moments in adam?