# Implementing KL warmup in tensorflow: tf.keras.backend.variable in callback is unstable over epochs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, callback, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement a variant of a Variational AutoEncoder with KL warmup in TensorFlow (paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02282)). The idea is that the KL term of the loss should be increased linearly over a specified number of epochs at the beginning of training.
The way I tried was using a callback that sets a value in a K.variable every time a new epoch begins, as the current number of epochs over the desired span of the warmup (for example, if the warmup is set to last for 10 epochs, at epoch 6 the KL term in the loss should be multiplied by 0.6). 
I'm also including an add_metric() in the KL (which is implemented as a layer subclass) to control the kl_rate during training. The problem is that the value of the variable is unstable! It starts close to the desired value at each new epoch, but it slowly decays on every iteration, making the process not very controllable.
Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm also not sure if it's a problem of the callback itself (and subsequently of the actual used value) or of the reported metric.
Thanks!

The imports:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

The callback (self.kl_warmup is a parameter of the model class that is set to an integer, corresponding to the number of epochs during which the kl rate should be increased):

```
kl_beta = K.variable(1.0, name="kl_beta")
if self.kl_warmup:

    kl_warmup_callback = LambdaCallback(
        on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch, logs: K.set_value(
            kl_beta, K.min([epoch / self.kl_warmup, 1])
        )
    )

z_mean, z_log_sigma = KLDivergenceLayer(beta=kl_beta)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
```

The KL layer:

```
class KLDivergenceLayer(Layer):

""" Identity transform layer that adds KL divergence
to the final model loss.
"""

def __init__(self, beta=1.0, *args, **kwargs):
    self.is_placeholder = True
    self.beta = beta
    super(KLDivergenceLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config().copy()
    config.update({"beta": self.beta})
    return config

def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    mu, log_var = inputs
    kL_batch = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var), axis=-1)

    self.add_loss(self.beta * K.mean(kL_batch), inputs=inputs)
    self.add_metric(self.beta, aggregation="mean", name="kl_rate")

    return inputs
```

The model instance (the entire model is built inside a class that returns encoder, generator, full vae and the kl_rate callback):

```
encoder, generator, vae, kl_warmup_callback = SEQ_2_SEQ_VAE(pttest.shape,
                                                               loss='ELBO',
                                                               kl_warmup_epochs=10).build()
```

The fit() call:

```
history = vae.fit(x=pttrain, y=pttrain, epochs=100, batch_size=512, verbose=1,
              validation_data=(pttest, pttest),
              callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, kl_warmup_callback])
```

A snippet of the training process (note the kl_rate that should be zero and it's off):
[image]

A screenshot of the kl_rate over epochs from tensorboard (the span was set to 10 epochs; after 10 epochs it should reach 1, but it converges to about 0.9)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a callback will work, but it's a little clunky. If you're happy working in terms of training steps (`iterations`) rather than `epochs` then that value is already being tracked/updated in the optimizer.

Creating a new layer is also a bit misleading if it doesn't have any variables or perform any operation. Using a custom `activity_regularizer` on the layer producing distribution parameters are a better fit here, and will prevent you from accidentally using the un-regularized parameters.

Without seeing you `SEQ_2_SEQ_VAE` it's difficult to give an exact code example, but hopefully the below gives enough of an idea about how to implement.

```py
class KLDivergenceRegularizer(tf.keras.regularizers.Regularizer):
  def __init__(self, iters: tf.Variable, warm_up_iters: int):
    self._iters = iters
    self._warm_up_iters = warm_up_iters

  def __call__(self, activation):
    # note: activity regularizers automatically divide by batch size
    mu, log_var = activation
    k = K.min(self._iters / self._warm_up_iters, 1)
    return -0.5 * k * K.sum(1 + log_var - K.square(mu) - K.exp(log_var))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()  # or whatever optimizer you want
warm_up_iters = 1000  # not epochs

inp = make_input()
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(...)(inp)
...
mu, log_sigma = ParametersLayer(
  ...,
  activity_regularizer=KLDivergenceRegularizer(optimizer.iterations, warm_up_iters))(x)

...
vae = bulid_vae(...)
vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer, ...)
```

If you have multiple things like this, you could use `tf.summary.experimental.set_step(optimizer.iterations)` and `tf.summary.experimental.get_step()` inside regularizers.

Comment: It took me a while, but I managed to make it work and it cleaned up my code by a lot! Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up discovering it myself after a bit more research.

```
kl_beta._trainable = False
```

did the trick :)
Thanks!

Comment: interesting.  looks like you are not the only one having this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102987/868736
I was not able to replicate the instability. but will set _trainable to False anyways!